# Quartz Job Not Participating in Spring Managed Transaction (Quartz + Spring Batch Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I have several spring batch jobs which work fine if the job execution is triggered in Spring Batch. These jobs will use JpaItemWriter to read and write to database, in which transaction is required.

My problem is, I have quartz scheduler which is configured to run these job periodically, I am getting "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress" error. I know currently the quartz is instantiating the job bean instead of spring itself, which makes the bean not aware of the ongoing transaction managed by spring, correct me if I am wrong.

However, I tried lots of ways, but none of them work. Below are my current configurations:

quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=sample_instance
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

SchedulerConfig.java

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

@Inject
private JobsListenerService jobsListenerService;

@Bean
public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
}


@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(JobFactory jobFactory)
        throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    factory.setGlobalJobListeners(jobsListenerService);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
}
```

Job:

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestJob implements Job {

    private static final String PARAMETERS = "param1=abc";

    @Inject
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Inject
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Inject
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Inject
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    private JobParametersConverter jobParametersConverter = new DefaultJobParametersConverter();

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            org.springframework.batch.core.Job job = jobRegistry.getJob("Job1");
            JobParameters jobParameters = JobParametersUtil.createJobParametersWithIncrementerIfAvailable(PARAMETERS, job);
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters).getId();
        } catch (NoSuchJobException | JobParametersNotFoundException | JobParametersInvalidException | JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already configured quartz to use JobStoreCMT. Do I have to explicitly declare a TransactionManager and pass it into the SchedulerFactoryBean? Helps are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To save other guys time around the world if you encounter similar or same issue as mine, here is what works for me.

I explicitly provided a transaction manager for the SchedulerFactoryBean.

```
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(JobFactory jobFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager)
            throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        factory.setGlobalJobListeners(jobsListenerService);
        return factory;
    }
```